# Reference Count Object

Tags: java, netty, nio

In netty, Objects processed by `ChannelHandler`(s) should be released by calling `ReferenceCountUtil.release()`. I am using customized objects in my application and documents says any object needed to be released should implement `ReferenceCounted` so it could be managed by netty framework.

So should we put a clean up handler at the tail of the channel pipeline to release incoming third party objects (I don't intercept outbound messages)? Did I get this idea correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the third party object is, but if it does not implement `ReferenceCounted` and it is reclaimed by JVM garbage collector without any problem, you don't really need to do anything.

The reason Netty expects you to release a `ReferenceCounted` object is because it contains something that 'must' be released immediately. (e.g. direct buffers, pooled buffers)

Comment: thanks for your answer. does that mean we can totally ignore self defined message objects?

Comment: @Korben Yes, as long as that object contains a `ByteBuf` or other `ReferenceCounted`